# Format ordered list <ol> CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a list something like this:

```
 1. Parent List.
   1.1 List item.
      a. List item's sub item.
```

This is the CSS that I found here in SO.

```
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}
li {
  display: block
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

however it renders like this:

```
 1. Parent List.
   1.1 List item.
      1.1.1 List item's sub item.
```

Comment: so basically you found something and you want something else? what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

You can just reset the list-style type and content for the third level li:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}

li {
  display: block
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}

/* change back to list item and use lower alpha */
li li li {
  display:list-item;
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

/* remove content */
li li li:before {
  content:'';
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> parent
    <ol>
      <li> child
        <ol>
          <li> grand-child</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: it works. however it also affected my navbar so I put the list inside the div so I tried something like this:    .content-div ol {counter-reset: item;} but doesn't work

Comment: Did you put the class before everything - ie at the start of each of the selectors above? Perhaps you should do a simple tutorial on css selectors as this is very basic stuff you're struggling with